# MPI_sendrecv changes loop index with -O1 flag

Tags: optimization, fortran, mpi, compiler-flags

My code is in a stable version now and I would like to enable at least the O1 optimization level to gain speed. However, I have found a really strange behaviour with a MPI command inside a loop with -O1.

In a preprocessing procedure, each MPI process needs to speak with the others (not necessarily all, that what the `SpeakWith` array is for) to exchange the number of cells they are dealing with (`cpt`). That is the goal of the following piece of code :

```
DO i=1,size(SpeakWith)
    write(*,*) 'BEFORE',i
    CALL MPI_SENDRECV(cpt(1+SpeakWith(i)),1,MPI_INTEGER,SpeakWith(i),ipas,n_recv,1,MPI_INTEGER,SpeakWith(i),ipas,MPI_COMM_WORLD,istat,ierr)
    write(*,*) 'AFTER',i
END DO
```

I have deliberately added some debugging `write` commands. When I compile and execute with no optimization flag, everything is fine. With the -O1 flag, I get, for 2 MPI processes :

```
BEFORE           1
BEFORE           1
AFTER            1
AFTER            0
```

As you can see, the index loop has been changed during the MPI command. The `i` variable has been declared with a user-defined kind `USER_INT` declared in a module :

```
integer, parameter :: USER_INT = SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)
```

`cpt` and `SpeakWith` have the same kind

I am suspecting a loop optimization that has been activated with the O1 flag, but still I'm stunned that the compiler has modified my code and let such a serious error occurred.

**EDIT** : A program to debug as requested that runs exactly in the same way than in my code.

```
PROGRAM test

USE MPI
IMPLICIT NONE

integer(kind=SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)) ::i=0,ierr=0,i_domain=0,nb_domain=1,n_recv=0,istat=0
integer(kind=SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)), dimension(:), allocatable :: SpeakWith
integer(kind=SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)), dimension(:), allocatable :: cpt

CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,i_domain,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,nb_domain,ierr)

allocate(SpeakWith(1))
allocate(cpt(nb_domain))
cpt(:)=0
IF (i_domain==0) THEN
    SpeakWith(1)=1
    cpt(2)=13226
ELSE
    SpeakWith(1)=0
    cpt(1)=15566
END IF

DO i=1,size(SpeakWith)
    write(*,*) 'BEFORE',i
    CALL MPI_SENDRECV(cpt(1+SpeakWith(i)),1,MPI_INTEGER,SpeakWith(i),1,n_recv,1,MPI_INTEGER,SpeakWith(i),1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,istat,ierr)
    write(*,*) 'AFTER',i
END DO

CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

END PROGRAM test
```

Comment: are you sure that `SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)` is compatible with `MPI_INTEGER`? also, what is the type of `n_recv`? it might be that the MPI call is receiving more data than `n_recv` can handle and thus overwriting some parts of the memory which might be occupied by other variables...

Comment: `n_recv` is `SELECTED_INT_KIND(9‌​)`. I was wondering that too but I checked with `sizeof` and `SELECTED_INT_KIND(9‌​)` is equivalent to a 4-byte integer as well as `MPI_INTEGER`

Comment: I am especially concerned about `istat`. We can't make sure it is declared with the right dimension in your code.

Comment: I have edited my post. Actually all my integers are declared and initialized at the same time, and indeed if I don't initialize `istat` to zero, it seems to work (I am not sure though) but I don't understand the relevance of initializing `istat` or not in the behaviour of the program.

Comment: Next time just use MPI_STATUS_IGNORE...